# Advice on Major Selection

Tags: mathematical-physics, soft-question, education

I need a bit of an advice in deciding my major. My university allows only one major (along with minors) and I'm having a little bit of trouble in deciding what to do. Here's the thing. I want to go into Theoretical Physics in grad school and so I have two options:

1. Major in Physics
2. Major in Mathematics + Minor in Physics

One thing I've realized is that I'm really bad at experiments and practical work (which rules majoring in Electrical Engineering out almost completely). I have this twitching problem that compromises my motor skills. Whereas, from my current academic standing it seems I'm good at Mathematics and Mathematical Physics courses such as Mechanics.

What path do you think will best prepare me for studying Theoretical Physics in graduate school? Your advice is highly appreciated. Thanks.

**Background Information on Course Structure**

According to my undergraduate student handbook, a Physics major requires 43 credit hours worth of core courses. Here are the core courses I'll need to take specifically for a major in Physics:

Calculus II
Electricity and Magnetism
Waves and Optics
Quantum Mechanics I
Mathematical Methods in Physics and Engineering I
Experimental Physics II
Classical Mechanics
Quantum Mechanics II
Statistical Mechanics
Electromagnetic Fields and Waves
At least one of: Atomic, Molecular and Laser Physics OR Condensed Matter Physics
At least one of: General Relativity OR Astrophysics OR Nuclear and Particle Physics

A Math major requires only 30 credit hours worth of core courses:

Calculus II
Linear Algebra II
Introduction to Differential Equations
Introduction to Formal Mathematics
Introduction to Analysis I
Introduction to Analysis II
Complex Variables
Ordinary Differential Equations
Advanced Calculus
Algebra I

Along with this, for a Minor in Physics I'll take (notice that now I won't have to take the Experimental Physics labs which I'm terrible at):

Electricity and Magnetism
Waves and Optics
Quantum Mechanics I
Quantum Mechanics II
Classical Mechanics
General Relativity

And since a Math major requires less credit hours than a Physics major, I can use them to take the following extra Physics courses:
Advanced Quantum Mechanics
Nuclear and Particle Physics

Comment: Maybe migrate to Academia.SE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm now a theoretical physics PhD student, and I did mathematics as an undergrad. In many ways doing mathematics prepares you very well for theoretical physics, particularly if you want to work in string theory or phenomenology. You'll pick up lots of useful skills for developing theories and doing calculations.

You should definitely make sure you at least minor in physics though, because you'll need the core knowledge from the courses you mentioned. I don't see any reason why a theoretical physicist must be a good experimentalist though - I'm also terrible at practical things!

Above all, make sure you do something which you are going to enjoy! If you don't like practical work, and are good at the more conceptual mathematics courses then I'd say major in maths and minor in physics.